# arcpy DLL load failed in standalone script

Tags: arcpy, python, python-2.7, 64bit, importerror

I have python 2.7 x64 bit and I have ARCGIS 10.5 x32 bit on windows 10.

I try to build standalone arcpy scripts but I take all time :

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: % is not a valid Win32 application.
```

where I want to import arcpy.

that error is because I have python 64 bit and ARCGIS 32 Bit.

but it possible to install arcpy x64 bit(or ARCGIS 10+ 64 bit with arcpy 64 bit) with the some way ?

Comment: You are right, it's a 64/32 bit problem. The bad news is that ArcGIS is still (mostly) a 32bit platform, you must use 32bit python. There is a few 'how to' on 64bit python like https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/12/python-scripting-with-64-bit-processing/ and http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm but, from memory, not the full suite of commands are available. You might have more luck with ArcGIS Pro, but from my readings on the subject it's no more 64bit than Desktop.

Comment: @Michael Stimson yes thx you for helping I need test it now...I have build many scripts in python 2.7 64 bit I scary to change now .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install 64-bit Background Geoprocessing.  This will install the 64-bit python, and a version of arcpy that will run with the 64-bit python.

Note that not all arcpy tools work in 64-bit:

> **Unsupported tools**
>
> Tools that do not run in the background include the following:
>
> - Tools inside the Metadata conversion toolset
> - Tools inside the Geodatabase administration toolset
> - All Coverage tools
> - Tools which create packages
> - Graphing tools (64-bit geoprocessing only; these tools work in traditional 32-bit background processing)
> - Data Reviewer tools (64-bit geoprocessing only; these tools work in traditional 32-bit background processing)
> - Custom script, model, or function tools where the author has disabled background processing
>
> You can check the General tab of the tool properties for the Always
>   run in foreground check box to see if a tool is capable of running in
>   the background.

64-bit Background Geoprocessing can be installed from the ArcGIS install media, or downloaded from the My Esri portal.

For more info see [Background Geoprocessing (64-bit)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm)

Comment: what you mean : _Custom script, model, or function tools where the author has disabled background processing_ I cant use model builder to help me like model to python script ? or what you mean _Custom script_ ?if I cant use my scripts is useless.do you have test it ?

Comment: @ChrisPapas Have you disabled background geoprocessing?  That bullet point reads "Custom script, model, or function tools **where the author has disabled background processing**".  If you haven't disabled background geoprocessing then the 64bit arcpy should work fine.  Yes I have tested it, almost all my arcpy scripts (hundreds of them) run using 64bit arcpy.  The only ones that don't (very few) are the ones that make use of the unsupported tools above.

Comment: @ChrisPapas I suggest you install it and try it. I think you'll find your arcpy scripts will just work using 64bit python after you install it.

Comment: first thank you for help,that I need is to build some models in ARCGIS using ARCGIS algorithm like IDW,topo to raster,reclass raster hydro analysis and raster analysis for my model and then that model export to python scripts and after from export add more things using python...that I need...you think I have problem with this task using 64bit arcpy ?

Comment: @ChrisPapas Like I said, give it a try.  Build something in Model Builder and export it then try running that in 64-bit arcpy.  That said, instead of Model Builder, try just running each tool from ArcToolbox, then from the "Results" pane right-click and export as python snippet.  I find the python exported as snippet often is better and tidier than what you get from Model Builder.

Comment: @ChrisPapas The best way to say "thanks" on Stack Exchange is to upvote and accept a correct answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)